# SQL grab all rows within past 5 days for each user and the first row for each user prior to that 5 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `Actions`.

Each action has a `user_id`, `created_at` and some other fields.

I'd like to run an sql query where I grab all actions within the past 5 days, for each user and the first action after that 5 days.

For example:
- if a user has no actions in the past 5 days I want nothing to be returned for that user.
- if a user has 1 action past 5 days and another 3 others, I want 2 actions returned for that user. The one within the 5 days, followed by the most recent of the other 3.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to write this SQL query. This has to be a query only, no procedures and no application level logic.

How do I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Context: Basically if I run this report then I can see whose been making actions on my site and see what their prior action was and when that prior action was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*, lead(created_at) over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as next_created_at
      from actions a
     ) a
where created_at >= now() - interval '5 day' or
      next_created_at >= now() - interval '5 day';
```

Comment: If table contains 2 recored with same created_at before 5 days for one user, query will return this 2 records.

Comment: @AlexSham is correct. I do have scenarios where people have multiple activities in the past 5 days

Comment: @TerenceChow . . . Multiple activities in the last five days isn't the issue.  The issue is multiple users with *exactly* the same `created_at`, which doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Unfortunately multiple activities can have the same created at. For example for actions that were backfilled or bulk imported.

Comment: Although I’m not sure why multiple activities with same create date is a problem?

Comment: @TerenceChow . . . `lead()` may or may not do what you expect if there are exact ties.  That would easily be handled with a unique key for each row, but you don't seem to have one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff there's an id field I can use. I'm going to accept this as an answer. thanks!